# Does it matter if I activate mementos in the ideal number of moves?

Tags: to-the-moon

Throughout the game, you're asked to complete various memento puzzles. The game keeps track of the amount of moves it takes you to complete a single puzzle and shows an Ideal score.

[image: screenshot of a memento puzzle]

It apparently even keeps track of the total moves that you've used throughout the game to complete the puzzles in the Overall score.

[image: second memento puzzle]

Does this number have any effect on the game's story or ending? Are there achievements associated with it? Does it do... well, anything?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I beat all the puzzles in the ideal number of moves in my first playthrough, and spammed my way through the puzzles in my second.  I didn't notice any difference at all, unfortunately.

---

**[Edit]** Apparently the developer is still [playing with adding achievements](http://www.ign.com/blogs/capitalistpig211/2013/01/07/two-new-achivements-added-to-to-the-moon), so perhaps there will be an achievement for this in the future.  However, when asked about this, [the developers' official response](http://steamcommunity.com/app/206440/discussions/0/828925849507987918/) was:

> ¯\_(ツ)_/¯